# After a conclusion of a bookmarked activity the instance no more persist/unload

Tags: .net, workflow, workflow-foundation-4

I've an application that host WF4.5 workflow in IIS using WorkflowServiceHost, WorkflowServiceHostFactory and WorkflowHostingEndpoint.

A have a custom activity for receive input data from a user. Get that using CreateBookmark and the callback for Resume.

```
IWorkflowCreation client = new ChannelFactory<IWorkflowCreation>(new NetNamedPipeBinding(NetNamedPipeSecurityMode.None), new EndpointAddress("net.pipe://localhost/workflowCreationEndpoint")).CreateChannel();

//create an instance
Guid id = client.Create(null);

// Resume        
client.ResumeBookmark(id, "1", "Message 1");
```

The problem is: After a conclusion of a bookmarked activity(createbookmark/resume) the instance no more persist/unload.

In other words, only the first bookmarked activity set instance do unload. And yes , I've set TimeToPersist/TimeToUnload.

Here is the tracking status of the instance:
*Started, **Idle, Persisted, Unloaded**, Resumed, Idle, Idle, Idle, Idle, Idle, Completed, Deleted*.

I created a sample solution that demonstrates the problem. [Sample for download.](http://1drv.ms/1uj9SEL)

I really appreciate if someone could help me. Thank you for any help!

Comment: Complement your first question with this information. Don't create a duplicate question, please.

Comment: possible duplicate of [WF 4.5 Bookmarked custom activity not fire persist/unload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26163481/wf-4-5-bookmarked-custom-activity-not-fire-persist-unload)

Comment: Tanks for the replay @Jota. But your answer no solve my problem, can you please take a look in the sample that i posted?